# Extract value from certain query from string in jQuery

Tags: javascript

```
var test = "http://www.example.org/search?q=whatever&another=moretext";
```

How can I extract `another`'s value (`moretext`) in the query string above and make a variable out of it?

Comment: This has NOTHING to do with jQuery. It's just plain old JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var test = "http://www.example.org/search?q=whatever&another=moretext";
var another = test.split('another=');
```

another is an array with another[0] = 'http://www.example.org/search?q=whatever&' and another[1] = 'moretext'.

Comment: what if 'whatever' contains 'another='

Answer (score 0):

keep this function in your bag :

```
 function querySt(qsName, url)
        {
            var theUrl;
            if (url == null || url == undefined)
                theUrl = window.location.search.substring(1); else theUrl = url;
            var g = theUrl.split("&");
            for (var i = 0; i < g.length; i++) {
                var pair = g[i].split("=");
                if (pair[0].toLowerCase() == qsName.toLowerCase())
                {
                    return pair[1];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

<kbd>Usages</kbd>

```
alert(querySt("another")+'      '+querySt("q"));
```